# Can you raise $\pi$ to a real power to make it rational?

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-function, pi

We're all familair with this beautiful proof whether or not an irrational number to an irrational power can be rational. It goes something like this:

Take $(\sqrt{2})^{\sqrt{2}}$

If it's rational, then you proved it, if it's irrational, take $((\sqrt{2})^{\sqrt{2}} ){^\sqrt{2}} = 2$ and you've proved it.

I'm wondering if you can raise $\pi$ or $e$ to a certain non-trivial **real** power to make it rational? And if not, where is the proof that it can't be done?

p.s. - I almost left out the **real** part, but then I realized that $e^{i\pi} = -1$.

Comment: I assume the word "non-trivial" in your question is meant to exclude $\pi^0 = 1$.

Comment: What am I missing? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt+2%5Esqrt+2%5Esqrt+2

Comment: @DoubleAA You're missing Brackets... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sqrt+2%5Esqrt+2%29%5Esqrt+2

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Indeed, I was trying to sound fancy, did I use it incorrectly?

Comment: Well... not incorrectly, just imprecisely. "Trivial" is one of the vaguest, most subjective and hand-wavey terms in mathematics; even in specific areas where it does have a reasonably well agreed-upon meaning, that meaning depends entirely on context. Anyway, if you were trying to sound like a working mathematician, I'd say you succeeded. However, I'd also say that's not necessarily something to be proud of. :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Of course. Pick any positive rational $p$ and let $x=\log_\pi p$, then $\pi^x=p$.

Comment: Derp, I am dumb. +1

Comment: Don't feel bad. It's easy to forget these things from time to time.

Comment: Doesn't this assume the answer is already true?

Comment: @Patrick: How so? You can define the logarithm without exponentiation. Define $\ln x=\int_1^x\frac1tdt$, then define $\log_p x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln p}$. You can now prove that $p^{\log_p x}=x$.

Comment: This makes sense using change of base.  Thanks.

Comment: A geometric way of "seeing" this: The map $f: x\mapsto \pi^x$ is continuous and strictly increasing, so its graph $y=\pi^x$ passes through a lot of points where just _one_ of the two coordinates (we want $y$) is rational.

Comment: @Jeppe: Except from rare occasions, the geometric way is never my way of seeing things! Thank you making that point, it wouldn't have crossed my mind. But the argument would be clearer if you state it as $f$ being surjective onto $(0,\infty)$, and therefore it hits every positive rational number.

Comment: @AsafKaragila doesn't the proof of the integral depend on exponentiation itself though? Can you define it without first proving ir? I'm not sure how any dependence would undermine the validity of the original assertion anyway though (unless there was some issue with existence of irrational log bases, but as you show, those are easy to show).

Comment: @Gruff: I'm not sure where in that integral I've used exponents, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you didn't, but you used a definition which (I believe) depends implicitly on exponents. The definition is correct but it isn't axiomatic so formally depends on a proof and I can't think how one could prove it without recourse to exponents (I could be wrong). I thought logs were axiomatically defined as the inverse of exponents but perhaps it's possible to choose different axioms and then prove they are mutual inverses, but if this is the case, I'm not sure what the axioms would be.

Comment: @AsafKaragila but as I said, I don't think it matters w.r.t. to Patrick's query about circularity. Axiomatically, the logarithm of x is *defined* as the exponent to which another fixed number, the base b, must be raised, to produce that number x. From that definition alone your original answer is demonstrably correct (unless one wants to get into the weeds of proving that log and exponentiation behave for all reals, including irrationals but I'm not sure this is necessary).