${rational}^{transcendental}$
Context: It is just a problem I made up myself, but curious if there is a theorem/method that can apply
I am interested in the question of whether a rational number, let's say, $\frac{p}{q}$, to the power of a transcendental number, $a$, can be an integer (for example, $2$). So basically whether there exists a case where:
$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^a=2$$
I am aware of the Gelfond–Schneider theorem, where a rational number to the power of an algebraic-irrational number always leads to a transcendental number, but am wondering whether there is some other method (or an "extension" of the Gelfond–Schneider) that can lead to a conclusion about the case I presented above.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399478/can-you-raise-pi-to-a-real-power-to-make-it-rational/ (Also, $\log_x y$ tend to be irrational in most cases).

Well, you know that $3^a=2$ has no rational solution, yes?  If it did, if $a=\frac mn$  then  we'd get $3^m=2^n$ which is impossible.  Thus, that $a$ in particular, $\log_3 2$, is transcendental.

For context see this question.

@DietrichBurde this in fact is my question haha. Do you happen to have an answer for the linked question?

The answer is Yes. It is well known that $\log_{10} 2$ is transcendental and $10$ is a rational number. Thus, considering the example $10^{\log_{10}2} = 2$ suffices.
